# How to add Foreign Key based on categoryid in different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2019

Suppose: a user can insert input via an interface, the input is about a food that is used to feed particular cats or dogs.

In the userinput table we want to save the foodid and the id of the cat or dog we're talking about.

We have the values, but:

- If the subjectid is a catid how do we check it exists in de cats table.
- If the subjectid is a dogid how do we check it exists in de dogs table.

[image]

I thought of the following solution, but I get 'Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.'

```
CONSTRAINT checksubject CHECK (
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cats c WHERE c.catid = subjectid) AND (SELECT categoryid FROM foods f WHERE f.foodid = userinput.foodid) = 0
    OR
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dogs d WHERE d.dogid = subjectid) AND (SELECT categoryid FROM foods f WHERE f.foodid = userinput.foodid) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (easily) do what you want with a check constraint.  You have a rather complicated dependency here.

Two possible solutions are:

1. Create a user-defined function that does the check.  Although you cannot put complex logic in a `check` constraint, you can call a user-defined function.
2. Use a trigger.

Or, you can restructure the data model to include the `categoryid` in bother `userinput` and `foods`.   It is possible to express this subsetting relationship using foreign key constraints and computed columns.

For this solution, you would start with a redundant unique index/unique constraint on foods:

```
create unique index unq_foods_foodid_categoryid on foods(categoryid, foodid);
```

Then add `categoryid` to `userinput`:

```
alter table userinput add column categoryid int;
alter table userinput add constraint fk_userinput_categoryid_foodid
    foreign key (categoryid, foodid) references foods(categoryid, foodid);
```

The foreign key reference ensures the the values are the same.

Then add persisted computed columns:

```
alter table userinput
    add column catid (case when categoryid = 0 then subjectid end) persisted;

alter table userinput
    add column dogid (case when categoryid = 1 then subjectid end) persisted;
```

And finally add the foreign key constraints:

```
alter table userinput add contraint fk_userinput_catid
    foreign key (catid) references cats(catid);

alter table userinput add contraint fk_userinput_dogid
    foreign key (dogid) references dogs(dogid);
```

Note that the persisted columns do occupy space.  But this allows you to have the "conditional" foreign key constraints without using custom code (i.e. triggers or UDFs).

Comment: So if I would include the categoryid in the userinput table, how would I build my constraint?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can have a conditional foreign key. Depending on your requirements there may be other ways to do it.

1. Add two nullable columns to UserInput table, one for the CatId and the other for DogId. Add a constraint to make sure one or the other is null but not both.
2. Store both cats and dogs in an Animal table with a column to indicate the animal type.
3. Split UserInput into CatUserInput and DogUserInput

You will really need to examine your use case to determine the best approach. For example, if you really must separate cats and dogs into two tables then you are modeling a many-to-many relationship between cat/dog and Food.

Answer (score 0):

Dogs and cats are specializations of the generalization pets.  Phrased another way, dogs and cats are subclasses of pets.  You could have a single table for pets, with a colun to indicate if it's a cat or a dog.
The key to this table,  PetId,  can now be used as a foreign key.